# Railsでモデルを使用しないコントローラーのparamsについて

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Railsでモデルを使用しないコントローラーのparamsについて質問させてください。

モデルというよりActiveRecordを利用しないタイプのparamsで、スマートにvalidationや複雑な処理を行う際にどのような方法が適しているのでしょうか。

処理としては以下のようなものなど。

- 問い合わせフォームのようなもので、DBに保存しないもの
- APIのやり取りなど

validationが中心になりますが、コントローラーで行わずに使いまわしの効きやすい方法など、お知恵をいただければ思います。

できれば具体的なサンプルいただけると助かります。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"DBを利用しないActiveRecord" のようなものとして、[ActiveModel](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activemodel) があり、バリデーションもARと同じように記述することが可能です。

以下READMEより:

```
class Person
  include ActiveModel::Model

  attr_accessor :name, :age
  validates_presence_of :name
end

person = Person.new(name: 'bob', age: '18')
person.name   # => 'bob'
person.age    # => '18'
person.valid? # => true
```